# AngularJS ng-repeat on update not working

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to display elements from an array in HTML that I push values into. The values are just basic strings.

This is the code where the database is set:

```
$scope.loadcourse = function() {

var db = null;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "note.db"});
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS note (name text primary key, data text)");
    alert("Loaded DB");
}, function(err){
    alert("An error occurred while initializing the app");
});

$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.courseDB = ["1","2"];
});

db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("SELECT (name) FROM note", [], function(tx,res){
          for(var iii = 0; iii < res.rows.length; iii++)
          {
              $scope.courseDB.push(res.rows.item(iii).name);
              alert($scope.courseDB);
          }
      });
  }, function(err){
      alert("An error occured while displaying saved notes");
  });


}, false);

}
```

This is how I display the entries:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="FeedController" ng-init="loadcourse()" class="has-tabs-top">

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="entry in courseDB">
        Hello, {{entry}}!
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
```

Now, the thing that doesn't make sense, is that it only displays the two dummy values (1 and 2), but does not display the elements that get added in the push-function inside the loadCorse function - even though the element that gets pushed into the array, is visible inside the alert popup that appears!

I'm almost 100% sure that I'm just missing one small stupid detail here.

**UPDATE**

This is how the array looks on alert: (no brackets)

1, 2, Textstring, Textstring, Textstring

Comment: `$scope.courseDB.push(res.rows.item(iii).name);` - shouldn't that be `$scope.courseDB.push(res.rows.item[iii].name);` ?

Comment: @JohannesJander Hmm that didn't work, it won't save it at all like that.

Comment: Sorry: `$scope.courseDB.push(res.rows[iii].item.name)` - after all, you are iterating `rows`

Comment: @JohannesJander Hmm it still gives the same error. Do you know what it could be? The res.rows.item.name returns a string without any quotes or brackets.

Comment: @JohannesJander Ah, I just thought of something: the string that is put in the array, contains multiple spaces and '-' in them. Since each string is not stored inside brackets, could this be what's messing it up?

Comment: We need a console.log of that whole data structure. Or better a JSBin/JSFiddle. without that, it'S hard to tell whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud trigger $scope.$apply() to trigger [change detection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle).

```
  tx.executeSql("SELECT (name) FROM note", [], function(tx,res){
      for(var iii = 0; iii < res.rows.length; iii++)
      {
          $scope.courseDB.push(res.rows.item(iii).name);
          alert($scope.courseDB);
      }
      $scope.$apply();
  });
```